# When I rebuild Visual Studio solution, I get the message "this program is blocked by group policy"

Tags: visual-studio, group-policy

Context:

1. Visual studio 2019 Professional
2. NopCommerce Solution 4.2

When I try to rebuild the solution I get message **"This program is blocked by group policy"** for the 25 projects in NopCommerce solution.

Please help, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it is to run  VS as an administrator, and then the rebuild is OK.